# ConnectApi.CommerceCatalog.getProduct on inactive product

Tags: connect-api, b2b-commerce, product2

I am working on a B2B commerce project and I have issues with deactivated products (IsActive=false)

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_ConnectAPI_CommerceCatalog_static_methods.htm#apex_ConnectAPI_CommerceCatalog_getProduct_2

It returns an exception "ConnectApi.NotFoundException: Resource not found." which makes sense but it is used to get the products's images in the order history for instance, which is not working anymore once a product is deactivated.

Is there an other API or parameters to use for this specific usecase or should I implement a workaround (SOQL query to get the medias for instance and fetch them with the CMS api)

Any insight would be greatly appreciated,

Best regards,
Julien

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We've had this issue before in our project, here is what we did.

ConnectApi Commerce class methods respects the structure of your storefront (I.E Entitlements, Pricebooks, Products)

So as a workaround:

1. we had to use [ConnectApi.ManagedContentVersionCollection](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_connectapi_output_managed_content_version_collection.htm) to retrieve medias attached to our community
2. we need to retrieve the medias attached to product using [ProductMedia](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_productmedia.htm) object

The implementation is something like this: (I cannot give you the full code due to NDA but hopefully you get the idea)

```
    // Give me all product medias based on the product ids given        
    List<ProductMedia> productMedia = new List<ProductMedia>([
        SELECT
            ElectronicMediaId, ProductId
        FROM ProductMedia
        WHERE ProductId =: productIds
    ]);

    // Content Id to be Processed
    List<String> contentIds = new List<String>();
    for (ProductMedia media : productMedia){
        // Key takeaway here is you will use the ElectronicMediaId and match it against the result of the media source node when you use the ConnectAPI ManagedContentVersionCollection
        ....
    }

    // Get Community images from Salesforce CMS based on the targeted products
    ConnectApi.ManagedContentVersionCollection contentList = ConnectApi.ManagedContent.getManagedContentByIds('CommunityId', 'electronicMediaIds From Product Media Query', 0, 100, 'en_US', 'cms_image');


    // using the Connect API ManagedContentVersionCollection
    for (ConnectApi.ManagedContentVersion versionItems : contentList.items) 
    {
        // Add to ConnectApi ManagedContentMediaSourceNodeValue List
        mediaSourceNodes.add((ConnectApi.ManagedContentMediaSourceNodeValue) versionItems.contentNodes.get('source'));

        // Loop through this node to be able to get the content id and media url
        for (ConnectApi.ManagedContentMediaSourceNodeValue nodeValue : mediaSourceNodes) {
            // Assign values to a map for getting
            mappingOfMediaIdAndUrl.put(versionItems.managedcontentid, nodeValue.url);
        }
    }

    // At this point you have the respective product image URLs and electronic media ids available for processing. Even if the product is inactive this can be used in the order pages
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi @malacdon, thank you for your reply !
Yes that's more or less what I had in mind for a workaround, I guess I will go that route